# Annotating figures in the obspy module of Python

Tags: python, annotations

I'm very new to python so sorry if my attempt below is pretty poor. I've tried to include as much information as possible as I know it's difficult to solve an issue without having a copy of the data being used to run the script.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to annotate points on a figure produced using obspy, where the x-axis is in UTCdatetime.

**General setup**

```
# Retrieve modules needed
from obspy.core import read
from obspy import UTCDateTime
from obspy.signal.trigger import classicSTALTA, recSTALTA, zDetect, plotTrigger, triggerOnset
from obspy.signal.filter import envelope

#path1 = 'rawdata/2015/EC/'
path1 = '../rawdata/2015/EC/'
station = 'BREF'
component = 'BHZ.D'
file = 'EC.BREF..BHZ.D.2015.342'
str1 = read(path1+station+'/'+component+'/'+file)

#sampling rate
df = str2[0].stats.sampling_rate

#crop for one test
t1 = UTCDateTime("2015-12-08T06:03:20.000000Z")

# other modules I might need
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Actual annotation section that fails**

I know that this code is probably a mess but I can't find any good documentation on how to annotate in obspy. Hopefully someone with a better understanding than me with python can make an educated guess?

```
fig = plt.figure()
str1.plot(color='b', starttime=t1, endtime=t1+40, number_of_ticks=10)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(t1+(on_off[0,0]/df),0), xytext=(t1+(on_off[0,0]/df)+5,0),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=1),
            )
plt.show()
```

*where on_off is a list of x-points at which I have marked, measured in samples - so samplenum/samplingrate = (seconds since t1)*

**Here is the output:**
[image: Output - annotations don't show]

**Further info:**

```
on_off
Out[95]: array([[1145, 1660]])

t1
Out[92]: 2015-12-08T06:03:20.000000Z

t1+(on_off[0,0]/df)
Out[93]: 2015-12-08T06:03:42.900000Z

t1+(on_off[0,0]/df)+5
Out[94]: 2015-12-08T06:03:47.900000Z
```

**Advancements:** 
*I'd really prefer to have a thick, horizontal line the length of a section that I want to highlight, with an associated text comment. However the arrow and label was the only annotation I could find an example for so that's what I am doing at the moment. If there's an easy way for the horizontal line between two points + text box, that's preferable!*

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a while working through this and found that the best method was to reassign the data and plot with matplotlib instead of the built in obspy module plotters, as they are designed more as 'preview' panes than as final figures.

I'm not sure it fits exactly with the code above but this is the code that  I'm now using that allows the annotating of figures:

```
fig = plt.figure()
data = str2[0].data
plt.plot(data)
plt.hold(True) #equivalent of matlab hold on   
plt.axvline(x=on_off[0,0], c='r')
npts2 = str2[0].stats.npts
plt.title(str2[0].stats.starttime)
l = plt.axhline(y=-4000, xmin=on_off[0,0]/npts2, xmax=on_off[0,1]/npts2, linewidth=4, color='r')
plt.show()
```

**Output is seen here:**

[image]

**Further info:**

A great webpage for further annotation options can be found here:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axhspan_demo.html